# How to align radiobutton list values horizontally and vertically in mvc4?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc-4

I have around 35 radio button list values to be displayed in my view using @html.RadioButtonFor html helper in a .cshtml page.

I want to display in 9 columns and 4 rows.

In Asp.net using control properties of  like "RepeatLayout", "RepeatDirection", "RepeatColumns" we could achieve this.

Same thing I want to apply it for mvc4.Is there any way to implement the same?

Please help!

Controller code:

```
ViewBag.Ratio = query.Select(m => new SelectListItem { Value = m.RatioID, Text = m.Ratio_Description });
```

.cshtml code

```
 <td colspan="3" >

            @foreach (var item in (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Ratio)
                  { 
                         @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.RatioType, new { @item.Value, @item.Text })
                        <label for = "@item.Value">@item.Text</label>

                  }


            </td>
```

Comment: You could adapt your CSS by using [nth-child()](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)

Comment: Please paste your code

Comment: Hi Jay, Here is my code

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to use table like this: http://jsfiddle.net/z2L3qbh9/1/
Or try to manage it with css like this:

```
.eachRadioBtn{
    width:11%;
    float:left;
}
```

wrap each radioBottuon with a div tag:

```
<div class=".eachRadioBtn">
    @HTML.RadioButtonFor( ... )
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Masoud, I cannot use like jsfiddle demo as I am fetching the values using foreach loop

Comment: @user3406037 you can just copy paste code from browser and paste it with css applied!

Comment: @user3406037, Hi. Try alternative way(.eachRadio). also in for each you can define a var like: int i = 0; When i%9==0; close previews tr and add new tr